# CSS position something on top without using negative values

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

this is probably really simple thing but i just dont know how to do it without using something like padding-top with negative values, my site looks like:

[image: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_9858499121396392876.jpg]

### My CSS is:

```
.center {
  width: 1030px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-panel {
  background-image: url("images/top_panel.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
  height: 43px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
a.top-button{
  background: url("images/top_button.png");
  height: 37px;
  width: 141px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block; 
}
.text {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  padding: 0px 160px;
  line-height: 43px;
  position: relative;
}
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="top-panel">
  <div class="center"> 
  <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
  <div class="text">Prave hraje 5000 hracov na 150 serveroch!
  <div class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</div></div>
  </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Can somebody really simply explain me how can i do it?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what the question is

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a fiddle with the issue maybe?

Comment: you can not give `negative` value to `padding`... because padding is inside the element ant it can't have negative dimension with itself... `margin` accept negative...

Comment: I am trying to make this: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_2087705911396393681.jpg?

Comment: Not sure what you want? Button centered? margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

Comment: I need that TEXT in same line as a BUTTON is

Answer (score 0):

I think you just messing with different HTML elements where there is no need to.
Try this:

CSS:

```
.top-panel {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("images/top_panel.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
  height: 43px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
a.top-button{
    float: left;
  background: url("images/top_button.png");
  height: 37px;
  width: 141px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block; 
}
.text {
  position: inline;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  position: relative;
}
.panel {
    position: inline;
    color: #6ab1ed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="top-panel">
    <div class="center"> 
        <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
        <p><span class="text">Prave hraje 5000 hracov na 150 serveroch!</span><br/>
        <span class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, it looks u know much more about it then me, anyway when i use your code my site looks like: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_19784547231396394327.jpg

Comment: make padding-top:0px;

Comment: HTML:
`<body>
<div class="top-panel">
<p><a class="top-button" href="#"><img src="images/top_button.png" height="37" width="141" alt="button" /></a>
<span class="text">Prave hraje 5000 hracov na 150 serveroch!</span> <span class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</span></p>
</div>
</body>`
CSS:
`.top-panel {
  background-image: url("images/top_panel.png") repeat-x center;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-button img {
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.text {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.panel {
  color: #6ab1ed;
  padding-left: 10px;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.top-panel {
     position:absolute; //or 'fixed' if you want it to stay there on scroll
     top:0; 
     left:1%; 
    right:1%;
}
```

Comment: why the down vote? perfectly working answer. Been using that forever to put stuff to the top

Comment: Right it wasnt me who downvote it, anyway it make my web looks like:
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_1903208781396393468.jpg

Comment: you want the bar to be at the top and it seems like it is so what's your question?

Comment: Nope i dont need bar on the top, sorry if i didnt descripe it as i should, i need it to looks like: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_2087705911396393681.jpg

Comment: put the main div that should stay at the top as I said in my answer. Everything that you want to be else in the top, put inside that div. OR you can assign position:absolute;top:0px; to each element and move it with left:100px (or wherever you want it)

Comment: if I helped you, please select this as the answer