# CSS move element to top without using negative value

Tags: html, css

This is probably really simple thing but I just don't know how to do it without using something like padding or margin with negative values, my site looks like:

[image: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_9858499121396392876.jpg]

and it should looks like: 
[image: http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_2087705911396393681.jpg]

So I need to display that text which is below atm, in the same line as the button

My CSS is:

```
.center {
  width: 1030px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-panel {
  background-image: url("images/top_panel.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
  height: 43px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
a.top-button{
  background: url("images/top_button.png");
  height: 37px;
  width: 141px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block; 
}
.text {
  color: #9c9c9c;
  padding: 0px 160px;
  line-height: 43px;
  position: relative;
}
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<body>
  <div class="top-panel">
  <div class="center"> 
  <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
  <div class="text">Prave hraje 5000 hracov na 150 serveroch!
  <div class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</div></div>
  </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Can somebody explain me how to fix it?

Comment: What was the point of making a new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798500/css-position-something-on-top-without-using-negative-values/22798535?noredirect=1#comment34765386_22798535

Comment: Give all info in first topic to all people, becuase in last topic i didnt and cant edit it so :)

Comment: well I answered your question like 5 times in the other post. Place everything in the main div that has to stick to the top and do what I told you to the div with position:absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNThy/2/)

**HTML**

```
 <body>
 <div class="top-panel">
    <div class="center"> <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
       <span class="text">Prave hraje 5000 hracov na 150 serveroch!</span>
       <span class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</span>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.top-panel {
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    height: 43px;
    padding-top:5px;
    display: block;
}
a.top-button {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 37px;
    width: 141px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    padding: 0px 160px;
    line-height: 43px;
}
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
}
```

Comment: Yea mate you are damm right!! Thanks a lot, maybe one moe small question is it possible to move that text 1-2 px up? if yea it will be perfect

Comment: yes you can give the `<span>` element absolute positioning. or turn the `<span>` back into a `<div>` and give it `display: inline-block` if you want the element relative positioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this.

### 1. You have all of your text in multiple block elements.

Block elements, like `<div>`s are on their own line. Replacing that with inline-block fixes that problem:

```
div.top-panel
{
    display:block;
}

div
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### 2. Your button is also a block element

So it cannot share the same line with your text.

Here is a **[very ugly fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8MfL/)**, but at least all of the elements are on the same line.